# Displaying a single parameter from multi parameter list

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have been struggling and hoped someone can help/provide hints.  My SSRS report has multiple parameters and I have page breaks in relation to the parameters.

In simple words I have a multiple parameter containing (and then displays their calories):
Orange, Banana, Kiwi etc

If the user chooses Orange and Kiwi, it displays the Oranges information on one page (page break) and the kiwis on the next.  In my header I want to capture to the parameters (Orange in first page, kiwi in second)

I seem unable to find any information besides a join which isn't the correct solution since join will display both orange and kiwi on both pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -- It will pull the array location = the dynamic current page number from the array of selected Parameters and return that array locations value:

```
=Parameters!YourParameter.Value(Globals!PageNumber-1)
```